# Replace line end with line end + double quote javascript

Tags: javascript, replace

I started something that appeared pretty easy, but it worked out differently.

I have this string, read from a file:

```
"columns:[
{
allowNull:false,
```

I want to replace the newline with a newline and a double-quote.

so I do:

```
text = text.replace(/\r?\n/g, '\n"')
```

somehow, the output is this:

```
"columns:[
\"{
\"allowNull:false,
```

I'm completely puzzled as to where the extra '\' is coming from. If I use a single-quote, or another character, it works just fine

What is going on here?

Comment: [Works for me](https://jsfiddle.net/gw3trLnf/), that code doesn't produce a string with backslashes in it.

Comment: I'm guessing that you're looking at this in an environment that shows you the string in double quotes, and that it shows you `\"` where a `"` is in the string because that's how you'd do that in a double-quoted string literal.

Comment: @Sjakelien, are you looking for final string to be -  columns:[\n"{\n"allowNull:false ?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a **very** active place. When you post a question (or answer), please *stick around* so you can respond to comments, edit or delete the question as necessary, etc., in a timely manner.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Sorry, I'm an active person, but not only only. On the up side: seems you were right. It was my IDE trying to show me what was going on. When printing to the console, the slashes were gone

Comment: Good good, I'm glad that was it! :-) Your best bet is probably to delete the question (which also gives you back the rep from the downvote). Happy coding!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I'll leave it here. I wish I would have found this question with your comments

Answer (score -1):

Within here

```
text = text.replace(/\r?\n/g, '\n"')
```

you replace with `\n"` instead of `\n`. As @vlaz indicates correctly in the comments, `text.replace` does not escape `"` to `\"`. But the `print` function does.

Anyway, there's a `"` which may be not intended.

Comment: No, it `replace()` doesn't escape quotes but printing the string does it.